# Distribution function of the quotient of a normal with sum of squares of normals

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, levy-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal random variables and $p\in (0,1)$. Show that $\mathbf P(\frac{Y^2}{X^2+Y^2}\leq p)=2/\pi\arcsin\sqrt{p}$.

How to prove this? Apparently the random variable $\frac{Y^2}{X^2+Y^2}$ seems close to the square of a t-distribution with 2 degrees of freedom, but this consideration didn't bring me very far.

Comment: The solution depends heavily on what you know and what you do not know. For example, are the words "polar representation of 2D normal" ringing a bell?

Comment: Hint: $(X,Y)$ can be realized as $X=R\cos\Theta$, $Y=R\sin\Theta$, where $\Theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$ and $R$ has an easy PDF which is irrelevant to solve the exercise. Thus you are asking for $P(\cos^2\Theta\leqslant p)$. Can you continue?

Comment: The factor $R$ disappears by itself since $X^2/(X^2+Y^2)=\cos^2\Theta$. Next, one would need to compute $P(-\sqrt{p}\leqslant\cos\Theta\leqslant\sqrt{p})$, not $P(\cos\Theta\leqslant\sqrt{p})$. Choosing the argument $-\pi\leqslant\Theta\leqslant\pi$, this yields $P(X^2/(X^2+Y^2)\leqslant p)=\frac1{2\pi}\cdot4\cdot\mathrm{Leb}([\alpha(p),\pi/2])=1-\frac2{\pi}{}{}{}{}{}{}\cdot\alpha(p)$ for some $\alpha(p)$ in $[0,\pi/2]$ depending on $p$. Can you end this, that is, essentially compute $\alpha(p)$?

Comment: If you know that $X^2,Y^2$ are i.i.d Gamma variables, then $\frac{Y^2}{X^2+Y^2}\sim\mathsf{Beta}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ (aka [Arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution)) from which the answer follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the above to be $$ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{Y^2}{X^2} < \frac{p}{1 - p}\right) \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{p}{1 - p}} < \frac{Y}{X} < \sqrt{\frac{p}{1 - p}}\right).$$ Then use the property that if $Y$ is normally distributed and $X^2$ is chi-squared (with 1 degree of freedom here) distributed then $X/Y$ is a Student-t distribution with $\nu = 1$ degrees of freedom (in this case).

For $\nu = 1$, the probability density function of a Student-t distribution is $f(t) = \frac{1}{\pi(1 + t^2)}$. From the above form of your question and setting $\alpha = \sqrt{p/(1 - p)}$ you get that the answer is equal to: $$ \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} f(t) dt = \frac{1}{\pi} [\arctan(\alpha) - \arctan(-\alpha)] = \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan{a} = \frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin{\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 1}}}.$$

The equalities follow from standard properties of the arctan function.

Comment: There's something I don't quite see: if $\alpha=p/(1-p)$, I come up with $\alpha/\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}=p/\sqrt{2p^2-2p+1}$, I don't get it equal to $p$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right - I meant to say that $\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{p}{1 - p}}$. I'll edit the response to show that.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful solution and straight to the point.